# Como hacer para que la opción Open(nombre_fichero) abra archivos sucesivamente

Tags: python

me pueden ayudar con el código Open, como podría hacer para que me abra un archivo y luego lo cierre, tengo archivos jpg guardados en una variable y deseo abrirlos de forma sucesiva.

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que pongas el código que tienes y especifiques un poco mejore lo flujo de lo que deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Pudiendo ver el código, mucho mejor para entender el problema, como comenta Jhoubert.

Aparte, por si sirve de ayuda, tienes la opción .close() y la opción de incluir el código en un wrapper. Por ejemplo:

```
f = open(file_name, options)
datos = f.read()
# haz algo con los datos
f.close()
```

o bien

```
with open(file_name, options) as f:
    datos = f.read()
    # haz algo con los datos
```